# Read input and exit on "^G"

Tags: bash

I am using the command

```
read -n 1 -p "$prompt" reply </dev/tty
```

to read one character from the user and execute the correct action. I would like to exit my program if the use pressed `Ctrl+G` instead of the allow inputs. However, I don't know how to do the comparison between `$reply` and `^G`.

Any idea how?

Comment: `[ "$reply" = $'\7' ]` works on my setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[ $reply = $'\x07' ]] && exit
```

To find it:

```
read -n 1 reply; echo -n "$reply" | hexdump -C
```